# Barra de rolagem apenas em uma div

Tags: css, div, layout-responsivo

Estou tentando criar uma tabela com apenas duas linhas. Minha intenção é que a tabela seja responsiva e que barra de rolagem apareça apenas na segunda linha caso o conteúdo ultrapasse a `height`. No **Chrome** funciona perfeitamente mais no **FireFox** não está funcionando.

**HTML:**

```
<table border=1>
   <tr>
      <td height="100">
         <h2>Cabeçalho</h2>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <div class="conteudo">
            <p>Olá Mundo</p><br>
            <p>Olá Mundo</p><br>
            <p>Olá Mundo</p><br>
            <p>Olá Mundo</p><br>
            <p>Olá Mundo</p><br>
            <p>Olá Mundo</p><br>
            <p>Olá Mundo</p><br>
            <p>Olá Mundo</p><br>
            <p>Olá Mundo</p><br>
            <p>Olá Mundo</p><br>
            <p>Olá Mundo</p><br>
            <p>Olá Mundo</p><br>
            <p>Olá Mundo</p><br>
            <p>Olá Mundo1</p><br>
         </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}

.conteudo{
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    background-color:#999;
    overflow: auto;
    color: #fff;
}

table {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}
```

Alguém me daria uma mãozinha??

Comment: Cara, o único problema é que as tabelas não são feitas para ser responsivas. Quando você seta as dimensões delas com porcentagem, você acaba deixando margem para erro, pois, como sabemos, os navegadores interpretam nosso código. Desta forma, meu conselho é que nesse caso, tente não resolver com porcentagem. E se possível, já que o tema é responsividade, atualize seu controle para uma lista, ou cards, que funciona muito melhor em aparelhos mobile por exemplo...

Comment: Entendo. Desconsiderando a questão da responsividade, porque será que no Chrome a barra de rolagem apenas na div funciona e no Firefox não? Alguma ideia?

Comment: Talvez por essa questão de implícito e explícito.
Sabe que o height tem umas frescuras com porcentagem ne? Ele só funciona se o elemento pai tiver uma altura determinada, e assim por diante. Tente colocar a altura, mesmo que em porcentagem, em todos os elementos pais da div. Estas questões costumam dar bastante dor de cabeça no cross-browser.

Comment: Aparentemente encontrei uma solução. Troquei a div conteudo por um iframe. Parece que resolveu. :)

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar a função [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) para setar a altura da `div` menos a altura do cabeçalho e adicionando `overflow: hidden;` no `html, body`:

```css
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.conteudo{
    width:100%;
    height: calc(100vh - 116px);
    background-color:#999;
    overflow: auto;
    color: #fff;
}

table {
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
      <td height="100">
          <h2>Cabeçalho</h2>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>
          <div class="conteudo">
              <p>Olá Mundo</p><br>
              <p>Olá Mundo</p><br>
              <p>Olá Mundo</p><br>
              <p>Olá Mundo</p><br>
              <p>Olá Mundo</p><br>
              <p>Olá Mundo</p><br>
              <p>Olá Mundo</p><br>
              <p>Olá Mundo</p><br>
              <p>Olá Mundo</p><br>
              <p>Olá Mundo</p><br>
              <p>Olá Mundo</p><br>
              <p>Olá Mundo</p><br>
              <p>Olá Mundo</p><br>
              <p>Olá Mundo</p><br>
          </div>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Pôr cara show de bola ... funcionou ... Eu já havia resolvido usando iframe ou invés da div. Mais era exatamente isso que eu estava procurando. Valeu. Um abraço.

Comment: @CíceroAntônio legal cara! Se puder marcar ✓ na resposta pra dar como resolvida seria muito bom. Abs!!